# Binning for numerical dataset in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am able to do few preprocessing steps in datamining using Hadoop MapReduce.
One such is normalization.
 say

```
100,1:2:3
101,2:3:4
```

into

```
100 1
100 2
100 3
101 2
101 3
101 4
```

Like wise am i able to do binning for a numerical data say iris.csv.

I worked out the maths behind it

Iris DataSet:  http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris

1. find out the minimum and maximum values of each attribute
   in the data set.

   Sepal Length |Sepal Width| Petal Length| Petal Width

   Min | 4.3| 2.0 | 1.0| 0.1

   Max | 7.9 | 4.4 |6.9 | 2.5

Then, we should divide the data values of each attributes into ‘n’ buckets .
Say, n=5.

```
Bucket Width= (Max - Min) /n


Sepal Length= (7.9-4.3)/5= 0.72
So, the intervals will be as follows :
4.3 -   5.02 
5.02 - 5.74
Likewise,
5.74 -6.46
6.46 - 7.18
7.18- 7.9
```

continue for all attributes

Are we able to do the same in Mapreduce .
Please Suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but what you want to do is to get the maximum and minimum for each of the attributes of that dataset, to then divide them, all in the same job, right? Ok, in order to divide the attributes, you need to feed the reducer with the max and min values instead of relying on the reducer to do the work for you. And I am guessing this is where your trouble starts.

However there is one thing you could do, a MapReduce design pattern called in-mapper combiner. When each mapper has finished its job, it calls a method called `cleanup`. You can implement the cleanup method so that it gets the max and min values of each of the attributes for each of the map nodes. This way, you give the reducer (only one reducer) only a collection with X values, being X the number of mappers in your cluster.

Then, the reducer gets the max and min values for each of the attributes, since it will be a very short collection so there won't be any problems. Finally, you divide each of the attributes into the 'n' buckets.

There is plenty of information about this pattern on the web, an example could be [this tutorial](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/the-in-mapper-combining-design-pattern-for-mapreduce-programming/). Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** you need to create an instance variable in the mapper where you will store each of the values in the `map` method, so that they will be available in the `cleanup` method, since it's only called once. A `HashMap` for example will do. You need to remember that you cannot save the values in the `context` variable in the `map` method, you need to do this in the `cleanup` method, after iterating through the `HashMap` and finding out the max and min value for each column. Then, as for the key, I don't think it really matters in this case, so yes, you could use the csv header, and as for the value you are correct, you need to store the whole column.

Once the reducer receives the output from the mappers, you can't calculate the buckets just yet. Bear in mind that you will receive one "column" for each mapper, so if you have 20 mappers, you will receive 20 max values and 20 min values for each attribute. Therefore you need to calculate the max and min again, just like you did in the `cleanup` method of the mappers, and once this is done, then you can finally calculate the buckets.

You may be wondering "if I still need to find the max and min values in the reducer, then I could omit the `cleanup` method and do everything in the reducer, after all the code would be more or less the same". However, to do what you are asking, you can only work with one reducer, so if you omit the `cleanup` method and leave all the work to the reducer, the throughput would be the same as if working in one machine without Hadoop.

Comment: Thanks Balduz for ur reply.Yes u understood my question.What i understood from ur answer is..Pls Correct me if i am wrong.Inorder to do binning in MapReduce we need to find min and max in cleanup() and let mapper() pass the min,max values to reducer.then after that let reducer calculate the buckets.

So if we are calculating min and max in cleanup().mapper will be responsible to collect all the attribute val right?so what will be mapper emiting (key may be the csv header and value will be the entire column).so reducer receives data from cleanup?Am i right?

Comment: See my edit, I tried to answer in a comment but it was too long.

Comment: Thanks Balduz.I will try out :).And update if i have any doubts :)

Comment: sure i will accept.But while reading a csv the mapper will only get each line. we need to get different col elements right?should i transpose the given file or write entire map data into a list after that extract each column from the list and add to Hash map

Comment: Each time the `map` method of the mapper is called, a new line of the csv is passed to it. Inside this method, you need to store the values of each column for the given row in the hashmap. Once the mapper gets to the `cleanup` method, it will have a hashmap with all the rows of the csv that mapper was passed. I don't know if what I just said is understantable...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46820/discussion-between-sree-and-balduz)